# JavaScript как построить пирамиду из чисел без повторения

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток! Прошу помощи так как просидел слишком много часов и никак не найду решения. 
Нужно построить пирамиду из чисел таким образом:

```
 1  
 2  3
 4  5 
 6  7  8
 9 10 11
12 13 14
15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30
```

И так далее. Суть в том, что сколько цифр в текущей строке столько раз ее повторить но без повторения чисел.

Вот что у меня есть(но работает не совсем так как я хочу)

```
var n = prompt("Введите число");

    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            document.write(' ' + j + ' '); 
            document.write('<br>'); 
    }
```

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Стековерфлов это не место, где вместо вас решают учебные задачки. Напишите, что у вас есть, и где возникла проблема.

Comment: Я в вашей пирамиде не вижу закономерности. У вас прирост хаотичный, то дельта равна: 1,2,1,1,1,4. При дельта - константа - строится без проблем. То что я вижу - проще "как есть" вывести в лог и не морочится с циклами. Пирамида действительно не получится и недолжна получится при таких условиях. Уточните что за пирамида имеется ввиду, или укажите чему равна ваша дельта.

Comment: Итерации увеличиваются до n-числа. Но как реализовать переход на следующую строку я не понимаю. Например первая строка выведется один раз так как одно число. Вторая строка уже два раза и т. д но без повторения чисел.

Comment: Если у вас лимитированая пирамида, с дельта = 1, и с граничной шириной n=4, то перестройте пример вашей пирамиды, потому что она построена не правильно. Не понятно почему на третьей итерации ширина 2, а не 3 (строчка `4 5`).

Comment: На третьей итерации ширина 2, а не 3 потому что во второй строке 2 числа а значит повторить строку с двумя числами 2 раза. И так далее. А n это просто максимальное число до которой строиться пирамида(оно вводится с клавиатуры пользователем).

Comment: Понял. Нужно дополнить числа пробелом и поставить моноширинный шрифт - тогда картинка сложится.

Comment: Прошу прощения за мое неумение излагать правильнее свои мысли. В первой строке одно число это 1. Значит будет одна строка. Следующая строка имеет два числа это 2 и 3, значит повторим строку по 2 числа 2 раза но счет будет без повторений. Далее уже три числа значит повторяем три строки по 3 числа. Далее 4 числа а значит повторяем строку 4 раза по 4 числа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм то вроде не сложен. Вам надо выводить 2 строки по 2, 3 строки по 3, 4 по 4 и так далее. Значит, надо считать выводимые строки. И когда счетчик такой станет равен длине строки, длину увеличить, а счетчик сбросить.

Вот собственно и все. В данном решении `n` - максимальное число. Вернее сказать, данный алгоритм выводит всю строку, содержащую это число.
`i` это сами выводимые значения, `len` - текущая длина строки, а `c` это текущий счетчик строк такой длины.

```js
var n = 100, i = 1, len = 1, c = 0 ;

while(i < n){
   if(c == len){ len++; c = 0; }  
   
   let row = [];   
   
   for(let k = 0; k < len; k++, i++) row.push(i);   
   c++;
   
   console.log( c + '/' + len + '| ' + row.join(',') );   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно писать document.write постоянно, достаточно в конце.
Вот решение где я храню выводимое число в currNum. Первый цикл выполняется для всех строчек количество которые указано в prompt, второй цикл выполняется столько сколько равен индекс строчки и во время этого цикла значение инкрементиться.

```js
const n = 10
let result = ''
let currNum = 1
let max = 1
let curr = 0

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= i && j < max; j++) {
    if (currNum < 10)
      result += ' '
    result += currNum++ + ' '
  }

  result += '\n'

  if (++curr === max) {
    curr = 0
    max++ 
  }
}

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = result
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Также не забывайте что prompt возвращает строку, скопировал у Вас и код сначала и не обратил внимания, иначе в цикле будет сравниваться со строкой.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но результат увы все еще не тот что нужно... Например в третьей строке должно быть все еще 2 числа а не 3. 3 числа будет на 4, 5 и 6 строке.

Comment: А, не заметил, переделал, вроде теперь так.

Comment: @Антон чем мой вариант не угодил, я даже вывел как у Вас в вопросе указано(